# Entity Framework Core 2.1 Breaks Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Since updating my API project to entity framework core 2.1 I've noticed an intermittent problem where ajax calls from my website return a response of `null` and response code of `400` rather than the expected result. The failures seem to affect every ajax call that is made but not every time they are made. For example if I have three drop-downs populated from the API on a page, one or two - but not the same one or two - will load each time.

I have resolved the problem by downgrading all of the entity framework packages back to the most recent 2.0 version but ideally I would like to be able to take advantage of the features 2.1 has to offer.

The EF packages I am using are:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

My ajax is vanilla js (I'm also using React) and looks like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('get', myUrl, true);

xhr.onload = function () {

      if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          //do something with data
      } 

  }.bind(this);

xhr.send();
```

The API methods themselves always work when I debug or call them manually through the Swagger UI. The problem only started when I upgraded to 2.1 and has disappeared now I have downgraded to 2.0. The problem has occurred in all the browsers I have tested (Chrome, Firefox and Edge).

Comment: Did you check browser console?

Comment: It just comes up with the 400 and null response.

Comment: Could you share the detail of API controller